# Spring Batch : One Reader, composite processor (two classes with different entities) and two kafkaItemWriter

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch, kafka-producer-api, itemwriter

`ItemReader` is reading data from DB2 and gave java object `ClaimDto`. Now the `ClaimProcessor` takes in the object of `ClaimDto` and return `CompositeClaimRecord` object which comprises of `claimRecord1` and `claimRecord2` which to be sent to two different Kafka topics. How to write `claimRecord1` and `claimRecord2` to topic1 and topic2 respectively.

Comment: By writing an `ItemWriter` that does this.

Comment: Exactly but I am not able to figure out how to add to delegates of two different entities in writer class and get the each entity from the CompositeClaimRecord to write to correspinding topic.

Comment: 1, writer, 2 topics, get the field values, put on topic? Why is that so hard?

Comment: Can you share some example in spring-batch application. I am using KafkaItemWriter class and trying to add two delegates whose key is same but value is different .

Comment: Don't use the `KafkaItemWriter`. Or use 2 in a composite itemwriter you write yourself.

Comment: I don't think that will make any difference as my challenge is to write two delegates into arraylist and then in write method with parameter List<? extends CompositeClaimRecord > claimRecs, writing to both topics using delegates. I am getting class casting error as it seems to think that the incoming record is of type CompositeClaimRecord for both teh delagtes but it is claimRecord1 and claimRecord2 for both the topics resp.

Comment: Why would you need a list. Just inject the 2 kafka writer, writer recrod1 to writer1 and record2 to writer2. Just create a dedicated writer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just write a custom `ItemWriter` that does exactly that.

```java
public class YourItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CompositeClaimRecord>` {

  private final ItemWriter<Record1> writer1;
  private final ItemWriter<Record2> writer2;

  public YourItemWriter(ItemWriter<Record1> writer1, ItemWriter<Record2> writer2>) {
    this.writer1=writer1;
    this.writer2=writer2;
}

  public void write(List<CompositeClaimRecord> items) throws Exception {

    for (CompositeClaimRecord record : items) {
       writer1.write(Collections.singletonList(record.claimRecord1));
       writer2.write(Collections.singletonList(record.claimRecord2));

    }
  }
}
```

Or instead of writing 1 record at a time convert the single list into 2 lists and pass that along. But error handling might be a bit of a challenge that way. \

```java
public class YourItemWriter implements ItemWriter<CompositeClaimRecord>` {

  private final ItemWriter<Record1> writer1;
  private final ItemWriter<Record2> writer2;

  public YourItemWriter(ItemWriter<Record1> writer1, ItemWriter<Record2> writer2>) {
    this.writer1=writer1;
    this.writer2=writer2;
}

  public void write(List<CompositeClaimRecord> items) throws Exception {

    List<ClaimRecord1> record1List = items.stream().map(it -> it.claimRecord1).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<ClaimRecord2> record2List = items.stream().map(it -> it.claimRecord2).collect(Collectors.toList());

    writer1.write(record1List);
    writer2.write(record2List);


  }
}
```

Comment: Would you call the YourItemWriter directly in the main step of job or you will add the delegates to the writer and then use them in write method of YourItemWriter ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I provided the whole implementation of the writer, what isn't clear about that?

Comment: I am able to write to two topic following your code. How to write them in a single transaction ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) with two `KafkaItemWriter`s as delegates (one for each topic).

The `Classifier` would classify items according to their type (`claimRecord1` or `claimRecord2`) and route them to the corresponding kafka item writer (`topic1` or `topic2`).

Comment: Can you share an example? I can see articles only with same entity types not with different.

Comment: Looks like I misunderstood your question because it's unclear. In the title you said `composite processor (two classes with different entities)`, but from the description you seem to be encapsulating things of different types in `CompositeClaimRecord`. A processor that takes `ClaimDto` and returns `CompositeClaimRecord` is a regular processor and not a composite one. A `CompositeItemProcessor` accepts a list of delegates processors and pass items to that chain of processors one at a time.

Comment: This answer does not work with your approach based on encapsulation, the answer by @M. Deinum is the way to go. I upvoted it.